# iOS Parse query for users returns nothing

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse for ios. When I query the user table with the code below, it returns nothing. There are a few users in the table and it should return all of them.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
NSArray *users = [query findObjects];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a user table that you created? The actual user table in Parse is not treated like a regular table. You may want to look here for reference: [parse forums link](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-currently-registered-users)

This is pretty much what you're looking for: `PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];`